# Mysterious NullpointerException after the built-in camera app saves my video properly

Tags: android, camera, nullpointerexception

I have an activity that allows you to record a video if you open a dialog and click on an icon.
The problem is that after I stop recording it throws a NullPointerException even though the video is saved properly.  According to Log Cat the error is not in my code so I tried to place "checkpoints" in my code and I found out that even the onActivityResult of my activity is executed properly so now I'm out of idea what to do.

Here is the Log Cat:

[image]

Code:

these are from my dialog that invokes the camera app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO); 


intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); 

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // set the video image quality to high
// start the Video Capture Intent

((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);



private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type)
{ 
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}


private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type)
{
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
  File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Movies",   "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + "/" +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + "/" +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

This code was more or less copied from the android developers site.
As I mentioned even the onActivityResult of my activity is executed properly(where I dismiss the dialog) after this.

Comment: Hi, I am using the same piece of code to save an image file(I'm building a Camera application). But the getOutputMediaFile returns a null. Why could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type)
{
  File mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg";
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4";
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return new File(mediaStorageDir, mediaFile);
}
```

The getExternalStorageDirectory method returns a File object, not a string you can append a subdirectory to.

It also wonder if the directory returned by that method would be available to a service.  The Android specs say:

> On devices with multiple users (as described by UserManager), each
>   user has their own isolated external storage. Applications only have
>   access to the external storage for the user they're running as.

LOL!!!! Just realized this question was asked 2 years ago!  Did you find the answer yet?? LOL